# Change parameter using Moq

Tags: c#, visual-studio, moq, mstest

I have a method to unit test (`GetEnterpriseInfo`) which calls another method (`GetAssetInfo`) from a class `AssetInfoManager`.

```
private EnterpriseInfo GetEnterpriseInfo()
{
    //some code
    //assetInfoManager is a public property,  deviceManager and enterprise are local variables
    assetInfoManager.GetAssetInfo(deviceManager, enterprise);
    //some code
}
```

I want to test this method so I mocked `AssetInfoManager` but I need parameter `deviceManager` to be changed according to mock. I have used `Callback` for that. `_mockAssetInfoManager` is mock of property `assetInfoManager` in above code.

```
_mockAssetInfoManager.Setup(x => x.GetAssetInfo(It.IsAny<IDeviceManager>(), It.IsAny<EnterpriseInfo>()))
    .Callback((IDeviceManager deviceManager, EnterpriseInfo enterpriseInfo) =>
    {
        //_deviceManagerGlobal is private global variable
        _deviceManagerGlobal= new DeviceManager
        {
            DeviceName = "Test Device"
        };

        deviceManager = _deviceManagerGlobal;
    })
    .Returns(_assetInfoList); //_assetInfoList is private global variable
```

I am able to see `_deviceManagerGlobal` change from the test but while I debug actual code I don't see `deviceManager` changing on line

```
assetInfoManager.GetAssetInfo(deviceManager, enterprise);
```

My requirement is to change that to mocked value inside `Callback`. Is it possible?

Comment: Is device manager injected or created within the subject under test? There are too many unknown variables to get a better understanding of the actual problem. It would be awesome if you could reformat the question with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we get a clearer picture of the current problem and what you are **actually** trying to do?

Comment: @Nkosi thanks for the comment, I have updated the question with some info about variables.

Comment: Use the callback to populate the desired members of the parameter passed into the mock. Even in the actual code assigning a new variable wont do what you are trying to do.

Comment: @lmad If you have mocked out the `GetAssetInfo` then why does it matter what was one of its calling parameter?

Comment: @PeterCsala actually that was a reference variable which was changed within the code. I needed that updated value. Got the answer, thanks to Nkosi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the callback to populate the desired members of the parameter passed into the mock.

```
_mockAssetInfoManager
    .Setup(x => x.GetAssetInfo(It.IsAny<IDeviceManager>(), It.IsAny<EnterpriseInfo>()))
    .Callback((IDeviceManager deviceManager, EnterpriseInfo enterpriseInfo) => {
        deviceManager.DeviceName = "Test Device";   
    })
    .Returns(_assetInfoList); //_assetInfoList is private global variable
```

Even in the actual code assigning a new variable wont do what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. We need to assign values to same object instead of creating new one :) basic reference variable behaviuor.